Can a landlord suddenly start charging for unbilled utilities?
We have been living in this new apartment complex in Los Angeles since mid-January. Our average water bill is around $26, give or take a buck or two.
We just got our June water bill that is $200 more than our average.
When I called the utility company, the woman said it looks like they just haven't been billing cold water, that we have only been paying for hot water.
I asked her if I had to pay this and she said, "Let me put it this way. You don't owe us because we really just do the billing. You technically owe your landlord because they pay for the utilities out of their pocket and use us to collect the money from the residents to pay themselves back." Very odd way of putting it, but nonetheless.
So, my question is... is this legal? Do we have to pay this? What complicates this further is that the woman on the phone said the account was established in November, but we didn't move in until mid-January. Brand new building, never lived in. And we were some of the first tenants in the building. Point being, I'm going to ask if they can provide historical data that shows how much cold water we used for those unbilled months to make sure we weren't charged for someone using the cold water in November, December, or early January. New building, so not sure why it would have been used, but when shifty shit starts happening...

Are you supposed to paying the water bill according to your lease?  Or does the lease say that you're only responsible for hot water?  And the June bill covers June's hot water + 6 months of cold water so ~$25/mo in cold water.  I would be curious to know how the water company can possibly separate the two-- it's not like they've got a hot water pipe and a cold water pipe running to the complex.

@JustinCave I don't think they're talking to the public utility, but rather the complex owner has hired a company to handle submetering and billing.

@JustinCave Central heating with separate pipes is a thing. Water isn't necessarily heated by each dwelling individually.

@Greendrake Yes, but the question gives the (perhaps misleading) impression that it is the utility company charging separately for cold/hot water. Utility companies don't connect separate cold/hot water pipes to buildings. I think the confusion stems from the fact that OP likely wasn't actually calling the utility company as claimed.

@Coryhott : you need to clarify exactly how this is metered and who gets billed by whom. As written this max little sense. If you have a dedicated meter, the utility company bills your directly and the landlord has nothing to do with this. If its a shared meter the utility company bills the landlord but has nothing to do with how the landlords bills you. There is probably a 4th entity here that does the billing on behalf of the landlord but without knowing exactly what and how they do it, we can't answer this.

@Hilmar If it's a new apartment, built since 2018, in California, then submetering and usage billing is required by law. Water conservation. For submetering, the public utility bills the landlord/condo HOA with their meter, and the landlord/HOA bills each individual unit to recover their costs.

england-and-wales
Utility bill charges are one of the "permitted payments" under Paragraph 9 of Schedule 1 of the Tenant Fees Act 2019.
If the contract says that the landlord can charge you for water, then they can. If it says they can charge you for "hot water" (which in reality means the gas or electricity used to heat it) then they can. If it doesn't say that they can, then they can't.
The fact that the landlord is using an agent to collect the payment is irrelevant. The fact that you are billed in arrears rather than in advance is irrelevant. However, they can't charge you for a period before your contract commenced. Even if the contract purports to be able to charge you for utility bills prior to you living in the property, it's likely that this would fall foul of the Tenant Fees Act 2019.

"The fact that the landlord is using an agent to collect the payment is irrelevant." If it were an administrative collector that might be true, but it's not irrelevant if the tenant has a contract with the agent to provide water, and the agent has a meter to determine usage.

It's not clear that charging for hot water is actually charging for the heating. I think it's likely that there's a single water feed to the boiler, then pipes to each unit from there, and these need to be metered. I'm guessing that they forgot to include the second meters in the water use until now.

@MichaelHall If the tenant has contracted with the "agent", then it isn't an agent in the legal sense of that word. An agency arises where Party A (e.g. landlord and party B (e.g. tenant) contract with each other, but Party A delegates actions under that contract to Party C who acts on A's behalf. In that scenario C is an agent of A. If instead Party B has contracted directly with C, then C is not an agent of B for the purpose of that contract. The phrase "You don't owe us because we really just do the billing. You technically owe your landlord" suggests that the contract is with the landlord.

That's kinda what I was trying to say in layman terms...
